# how to get id of drop item in shapeshift jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shapeshift

i want to remove the an item from server side also , so i need `id` of item that is gone to `trash div`, below method is called on when dropped to `trash div`.

```
drop: function(e, selected) {
              var $current_container, $original_container, $previous_container;
              if (_this.options.enableTrash) {
                  alert(original_container_class);
                $original_container = $("." + original_container_class);
                $current_container = $("." + current_container_class);
                $previous_container = $("." + previous_container_class);
                $selected = $(selected.helper);
                $current_container.trigger("ss-trashed", $selected);
                $selected.remove();
                $original_container.trigger("ss-rearrange").removeClass(original_container_class);
                $current_container.trigger("ss-rearrange").removeClass(current_container_class);
                return $previous_container.trigger("ss-arrange").removeClass(previous_container_class);
              }
            }
```

**FIDDLE:**
 http://jsfiddle.net/LNysC/2244/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.trash').on('ss-trashed', function (e, selected) {
    console.log($(selected).attr('id'))
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/LNysC/2245/